# Delete key and subkey from registry:Code throw unhandled exception

Tags: c++, visual-c++, access-violation

I want to delete the Registry key and the all subkey.I am using the code from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724235%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Code compile fine but when debug the code

```
"Unhandled exception at 0x00416d14 in deletedemo.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0041ff01."
```

exception occur at the line

```
// Check for an ending slash and add one if it is missing.

    lpEnd = lpSubKey + lstrlen(lpSubKey);

    if (*(lpEnd - 1) != TEXT('\\')) 
    {
        *lpEnd =  TEXT('\\'); //Here exception occur.
        lpEnd++;
        *lpEnd =  TEXT('\0');
    }
```

Comment: What is the length of lpSubKey when this code throws the error???

Comment: Value of lpSubKey is 0x00000025.

Comment: The MSDN example is a messy way to do the task.

Comment: Then the character array you have used to store the lpSubKey must be small to throw this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a code to delete the Registry Key and its Subkeys recursively some time ago. The code goes like this::

```
static BOOL RcrsvRegDel( HKEY hKey, LPTSTR lpszSub, DWORD dwOpenFlags )
{
BOOL    bRet = TRUE ;
LONG    lRet ;
DWORD   dwSize = MAX_PATH ;
TCHAR   szName[MAX_PATH] ;
HKEY    hKeySub = NULL ;
HRESULT hr = NULL ;
HANDLE  hProcess = NULL ;
HANDLE  hToken = NULL ;

do{
    lRet = RegOpenKeyEx( hKey, lpszSub, 0, dwOpenFlags, &hKeySub ) ;
    if( lRet != ERROR_SUCCESS )
    {
        bRet = FALSE ;
        break ;
    }

    while( ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS != (lRet = RegEnumKeyEx(hKeySub, 0, szName, &dwSize, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL)) )
        if( !RcrsvRegDel(hKeySub, szName, dwOpenFlags) ) 
        {
            bRet = FALSE ;
            break ;
        }

    lRet = RegDeleteKey( hKey, lpszSub ) ;
    printf("RegDelKey:: %S :: lRet = %ld\n", lpszSub, lRet) ;
    if( lRet != ERROR_SUCCESS )
    {
        bRet = FALSE ;
        break ;
    }

    if( hKeySub != NULL )
    {
        RegCloseKey(hKeySub) ;
        hKeySub = NULL ;
    }
}while(0) ;
return bRet ;
}
```

dwOpenFlags = Flags to be passed to RegOpenKeyEx or RegDeleteKey.

**EDIT**:: If you do not want to delete the whole tree yourself recursively, MSDN have two functions to do this. You  can always use them, namely, [RegDeleteTree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379776%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [SHDeleteKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773486%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).